# Fail to run "linkDebugFrameworkIos" in Kotlin Multiplatform when linking iOS Framework

Tags: ios, kotlin, interop, kotlin-native, kotlin-multiplatform

I am trying to link an iOS .framework to Kotlin Multiplatform/Native so that I can use it in Kotlin. I successfully link the Framework to the Kotlin Multiplatform/Native successfully and the proper packages contains the headers that I linked up.

However `Undefined symbols for architecture` happens whenever I tried to build the project.

I have tried compiling to different architecture for iPhone Simulator on `iosX64` preset and for iPhone `iosArm64` preset.

And I tried adding the .framework itself to a vanilla XCode project and it runs fine on both simulator and iPhone.

Here is the `.def` file

```
// engine.def
language = Objective-C

package = org.djinnihello
headers = DjinniHelloLib2.h
headerFilter = **
```

And here is a section of the `build.gradle` file

```
//build.gradle
targets {
    fromPreset(presets.android, 'android')
    // This preset is for iPhone emulator
    // Switch here to presets.iosArm64 (or iosArm32) to build library for iPhone device
    fromPreset(presets.iosArm64, 'ios') {
        compilations.main {
            outputKinds('FRAMEWORK')
            cinterops {
                def productsDir = rootProject.file("iosApp/iosApp/Framework").absolutePath
                println(productsDir)
                hello {
                    defFile project.file("src/engine.def")
                    compilerOpts "-F${productsDir} -framework DjinniHelloLib2"
                    linkerOpts "-F${productsDir} -framework DjinniHelloLib2"
                    includeDirs "$productsDir/DjinniHelloLib2.framework/Headers"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the error message that popped up when I tried to build it in XCode or running `./gradlew linkDebugFrameworkIos`

```
> Task :app:cinteropHelloIos UP-TO-DATE

> Task :app:linkDebugFrameworkIos FAILED
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_HWHelloWorld", referenced from:
     objc-class-ref in combined.o
       ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
```

Comment: Could you please give us the link to documentation about creating *.def files for frameworks? Did you do it by hands or with some tool?

Comment: Hi, I did it by hand with repeated trial and errors. Unfortunately, there is not much documentation other than https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-native/blob/master/INTEROP.md and https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/native/c_interop.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the answer:

As of Kotlin Multiplatform `1.1.1` `linkerOpts` and `compilerOpts` in `build.gradle` do nothing. They have to be in the `.def` file in order to compile and run.

```
language = Objective-C

package = org.djinnihello
headers = DjinniHelloLib2.h
headerFilter = **

compilerOpts = -F/absolute/path/to/Framework -framework DjinniHelloLib2
linkerOpts = -F/absolute/path/to/Framework -framework DjinniHelloLib2
```

Comment: I'm having a similar problem described https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64864812/not-able-to-add-ios-custom-framework-to-a-kmm-kotlin-multi-platform-module-ci.

Comment: Sorry the last comment is not complete. do you know if this happens too in the version 1.4.10 of kotlin native?